# Sending HTML email from PHP

Tags: php, html, email

I am trying to send a simple HTML e-mail from PHP.  The code below simply results in a blank e-mail in GMail.  It also has an empty attachment called 'noname', which is not at all what I want; though that might just be a symptom of it not working.

The code I am using is:

```
<?php
//define the receiver of the email
$to = 'morrillkevin@gmail.com';
//define the subject of the email
$subject = 'Test HTML email';
//create a boundary string. It must be unique
//so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com";
//add boundary string and mime type specification
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-alt-".$random_hash."\"";
//define the body of the message.
ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering
?>
--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello World!!! 
This is simple text email message. 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<p>This is something with <b>HTML</b>formatting.</p>

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--
<?
//copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer
$message = ob_get_clean();
//send the email
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed" 
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out the key is the encoding type.  Instead of:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
```

I needed to use:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

It might depend on stuff as detailed as how you save the PHP file in your own text editor.  I haven't looked into it, but the **iconv** function in PHP may have brought me some joy too.  So I think this part is really sensitive.

Here is a better snippet of sample code that shows the whole thing end-to-end:

```
$notice_text = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.";
$plain_text = "This is a plain text email.\r\nIt is very cool.";
$html_text = "<html><body>This is an <b style='color:purple'>HTML</b> text email.\r\nIt is very cool.</body></html>";

$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==MULTIPART_BOUNDARY_$semi_rand";
$mime_boundary_header = chr(34) . $mime_boundary . chr(34);

$to = "Me <foo@gmail.com>";
$from = "Me.com <me@me.com>";
$subject = "My Email";

$body = "$notice_text

--$mime_boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$plain_text

--$mime_boundary
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$html_text

--$mime_boundary--";

if (@mail($to, $subject, $body,
    "From: " . $from . "\n" .
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
    "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;\n" .
    "     boundary=" . $mime_boundary_header))
    echo "Email sent successfully.";
else
    echo "Email NOT sent successfully!";

exit;
```

-Kevin

Answer (score 9):

If possible use the [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) class. It will greatly simplify your work.

Answer (score 6):

You have to specify the mime-type within the headers-parameter of the mail-function. Add this:

```
$header  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

It's also shown in the [PHP-Documentation for the mail-function](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). See example 4

Comment: This won't work, because I need a multi-part message with both test and HTML.  I tried adding MIME to both, and that doesn't help, though I think you're right that it is required.  So I must have an additional problem on top of that.

Answer (score 3):

If using a library is not a problem just use [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)

Comment: I tried Pear mail to no avail.  I general I am trying to minimize dependencies and actually understand how this works.

Comment: There are multiple examples on the Swift Mailer documentation. Unlike PEAR Mail It doesn't have dependencies

Answer (score 0):

There is something important I want to notice about charsets here:

`"Content-Type: text/plain; charset = \"UTF-8\";\n"`

is right and not only

`"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"`

Hope I could help other people who frustrate while searching the same mistake like me.

Remember also to write only \r for windows and not for Linux-Servers.
And at the end of the header should be an extra blank line:

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset = \"UTF-8\";\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n";
$headers .= "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code is working for me to remove HTML Tags in mail.

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";      
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps you in php

```
$fname=$_POST['FirstName'];
$lname=$_POST['LastName'];
$dob=$_POST['DOB'];
$name=$fname.'  '.$lname;


$HTML="
<style>
<!--
.form_tbl{ border:1px solid #bbbbbb; background-color:#eeeeee;}
.form_tbl td{
    font-size:12px;
    color:#555555;
    padding:5px 5px;
}
h3{ 
    font-family:Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#0099CC;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.form_tbl td select{ margin:0; padding:0;}
.tbl_brdr{ border-top:1px solid #bbbbbb; border-left:1px solid #bbbbbb;}
.tbl_brdr td{ border-bottom:1px solid #bbbbbb;  border-right:1px solid #bbbbbb; padding:5px 5px 5px 10px; }
-->
</style>

<table class='form_tbl' width='650' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3'>

    <tr>
      <td colspan='2'><strong>PERSONAL DETAILS:</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width='250' > Name:</td>
      <td >".$name."</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td  valign='middle'>Date Of Birth:</td>
      <td  valign='top'>".$dob."</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
";

$from=$name;
$subject='Student Registration Form';
$to= 'yourmail@mail.com';
//$to='development@ezone.com.np';
function sendHTMLemail($HTML,$from,$to,$subject)
{
// First we have to build our email headers
// Set out "from" address

    $headers = "From: $from\r\n"; 

// Now we specify our MIME version

    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 

// Now we attach the HTML version

    $headers .= //"--$boundary\r\n".
                "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
                //"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
// And then send the email ....

    if (mail($to,$subject,$HTML,$headers)) 
{

  $_SESSION['msg']="Details successfully sent!";

} 
else 
{
  $_SESSION['msg']="Sending Failed! Please try again later.";

}
}
sendHTMLemail($HTML,$from,$to,$subject);
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't include a text part to the e-mail, so it won't work for what I need.