# HTML email just shows as Code

Tags: php, html, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending HTML email from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058897/sending-html-email-from-php)

Using PHP to send an email.

I want it to be HTML based but when I get the email in my inbox it just shows the raw code.

How can I make it interprited as HTML rather then just text?!

For everyone asking to see the code

```
<?php
//The email of the sender
$email = $_POST['email'];
//The message of the sender
$message = "<html></html>";
//The subject of the email
$subject = "Fanshawe Student Success";
$extra = $email."\r\nReply-To: ".$email."\r\n";
mail($email,$subject,$message,$extra);
?>
```

Comment: How about *you* show some code so that we know what you're talking about.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=html+e-mail+php and http://php.net/mail (example #4)

Comment: Maybe you should show us code where you send email?

Comment: Use [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) and stop building your own MIME messages.

Comment: phpMailer Class is a good start!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

from the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

obviously $headers has to be passed to the mail

Comment: I think the problem is much deeper :D

Answer (score 5):

here you go:

```
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'someemail@address.com';

//subject
$subject = 'Email Template for Lazy People';

//message body
$message = "
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <b>My email body</b>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
";

//add headers
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: yourself<info@yourself.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: myself<info@myself.com>' . "\r\n";

//send mail
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Thanks all, 

Our Prof. never went over headers when we went over mailscripts so it was not so obvious for me. But greatly Appreciated!