# How to send HTML email through PHP

Tags: php, html, email

I've found instructions online how to do this, but it's not working for me... My shortened PHP message is:

```
$msg = '<html><body>';
$msg .= 'Dear' .$firstname. 'Best wishes';
$msg .= '</body></html>';
```

I'm intending to actually add some html INTO the message, but this just comes out with:

```
<html><body>
Dear Sam Best wishes
</body></html>
```

What am I missing?! Thanks.

Comment: Sorted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860806/html-email-just-shows-as-code

Comment: Check your `Content-type` header

Comment: Okay, I see you figured it out

Comment: $headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' ; add header content type = text/html

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this instructions, that is added in [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). And here is a working example that you could compare to your code.

```
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com';
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```