# HTML emails using mailto() function in php

Tags: php, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending HTML email from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058897/sending-html-email-from-php)

I need to send an html mail using the php `mailto()` function. I have the mail.html(which is the body of the mail i need to send) in the same folder where I have kept the mailing script. I want the content of the html content in the body of the mail and not as an attachment. How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could start with the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Show is the code you're using to do this and explain what it does instead of working.  Don't forget to include a non-HTML version of the email as well.  Many spam filters will score mail higher as spam if it contains a text/plain part that doesn't match the text/html part, or if it doesn't contain a text/plain part at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just be sure to add a HTML header to your mail:

```
<?php
$header = "Content-Type: text/html\n";   
mail($to, $subject, $text, $header);
?>
```

Comment: Now you can put HTML-code into your $text var: $text = "<span style=\"font-weight:bold\">I'm a bold text</span>";

Comment: Well, actually i have a file already. so i need to copy pate the content of that file to here?

Comment: check out http://php.net/manual/de/function.fopen.php and http://php.net/manual/de/function.fread.php if you have a concrete question, feel free to ask

Comment: Well, i tried it, but i had some images to be embedded into the body. it is not going. How can i do that?