# Send HTML mails using PHP

Tags: php, html, ssmtp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending HTML email from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058897/sending-html-email-from-php)

I am sending emails using php through my gmail account. And I am using ssmtp other than sendmail. I am using following php code to send the mail.

```
$to = "mymail@gmail.com";
$from = "mymail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Testing mail";
$header  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset: utf8\r\n";     
$headers = "From:" . $from;
$message = "<html><body><head></head>";
$message .= "<h1>Hello, World!</h1>";
$message .= "</body></html>";

if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
   echo "Mail Sent.";
} else {
   echo 'failed';
}
```

But I am getting a mail like below

```
<html><body><head></head><h1>Hello, World!</h1></body></html>
```

What may be the reason for it? I am using ssmtp MTA in Ubuntu.

Comment: `Content-type: text/html; charset:` should be `Content-type: text/html; charset=`

Comment: html emails are evil. They are the main source of malware infections these days. Don't use them.

Comment: You should have a look to libraries such as [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html) which are cleaner and safer ways to send emails.

Comment: change `$header` for `$headers` and it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
<?php
$to = "mymail@gmail.com";
                $from = "mymail@gmail.com";
                $subject = "Testing mail";
                $header  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

        $header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

                $header .= "From:" . $from;

                $message = "<html><body><head></head>";
                $message .= "<h1>Hello, World!</h1>";
                $message .= "</body></html>";

                if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
                echo "Mail Sent.";
                } else {
                echo 'failed';
                }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks.. I had dropped a '.' when attaching another one to the header. I didn't see it. Now it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following in your code

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

This link will be most helpful

[Sending HTML email with PHP](http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/)

Comment: Hai Frankline..I am following that link..But still I got same mail..Is it because ssmtp?

Comment: Does it work when you send via simple `SMTP`?

Answer (score 1):

You are using header (singular) and headers (plural) indistinctly. The correct way is using plural for the headers:

```
$headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

This is a good reading:
http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

Thats because PHP does not make new lines by it self. You can use echo "Lalala \n" to make new lines.