# Formatting HTML with PHP Mail

Tags: php, email

I've been working through this thread here:
[Sending HTML email from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058897/sending-html-email-from-php)

For the last 5 hours and for some reason cannot get my PHP to generate HTML mail.

Here's what I have:

```
// Construct Mail:
$message = "<html><body>Some text<br />New line<p>New para</p></body></html>";
// Send Mail:
$to         = "$UserMail";
$subject        = "[Skills Exchange Network] Event Created";
$header     = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$header     .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers    .= 'From: Skills Exchange Network <Mail Address is here>' . "\r\n";
$headers    .= 'Cc: Skills Exchange Network <Mail Address is here>' . "\r\n";
$SendMail   = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Here's what I receive:

> From Skills Exchange Network  rnCc: Skills Exchange Network rn

I'm truly at a loss...

Here's what I have now:

```
// Construct Mail:
$message = "<html><body>Some text<br />New line<p>New para</p></body></html>";

// Send Mail:
$to         = "$UserMail";
$subject        = "[Skills Exchange Network] Event Created";

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers     = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers    .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" . "\r\n";

// Additional Headers:
$headers    .= "From: Skills Exchange Network <info@skillsexchangenetwork.net>" . "\r\n";
$headers    .= "Cc: Skills Exchange Network <info@skillsexchangenetwork.net>" . "\r\n";
$SendMail   = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

And here's what I receive:

```
Subject: [Skills Exchange Network] Event Created
MIME-Version: 1.0rnContent-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1rnFrom: Skills Exchange     Network <info@skillsexchangenetwork.net>rnCc: Skills Exchange Network <info@skillsexchangenetwork.net>rn
Message-Id: <E1UzptE-0003e1-Fs@wdt.webserversystems.com>
From: skillsex@wdt.webserversystems.com
Date: Thu, 18 Jul 2013 10:13:08 -0500
X-Antivirus: AVG for E-mail 2013.0.3349 [3204/6500]
X-AVG-ID: ID58DD9571-36429B43

<html><body>Some text<br />New line<p>New para</p></body></html>
```

Comment: Best is to use tables for email markup

Comment: Is this the e-mail body you are receiving or is this the subject?

Comment: There are 2 things at fault: The headers and the body. I get the mail but with malformed headers and the HTML comes as plain text. Probably because the headers are wrong.

Comment: Use a proper library like SwiftMailer. There's no good reason to do it manually with `mail()`.

Comment: I've been doing it this way as it's code running on the server. Are you suggesting SwiftMailer for a specific reason...? Also, as much as I'd like to use SwiftMailer it won't run within my system.

Answer (score 1):

You are naming `$headers` as `$header` and because of that your content-type is not embedding.

```
$headers     = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers    .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers    .= 'From: Skills Exchange Network <Mail Address is here>' . "\r\n";
$headers    .= 'Cc: Skills Exchange Network <Mail Address is here>' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Thanks Yogesh

I implemented what you suggested:

I now still get an error in the headers.
    MIME-Version: 1.0rnContent-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1rnFrom: Skills Exchange Network <info@skillsexchangenetwork.net>rnCc: Skills Exchange Network <info@skillsexchangenetwork.net>rn

Clearly I still have an issue.

Comment: In fact, it's not doing two things:

Breaking the headers apart and formatting the HTML.

I get the mail OK but not formatted correctly or with the headers loading correctly.

Comment: Here's what I have now

// Construct Mail:
 $message = "HTML code here";

// Send Mail:
 $to   = "$UserMail";
 $subject  = "[Skills Exchange Network] Event Created";

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
 $headers     = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
 $headers    .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" . "\r\n";

// Additional Headers:
 $headers    .= "From: Skills Exchange Network <info@skillsexchangenetwork.net>" . "\r\n";
 $headers    .= "Cc: Skills Exchange Network <info@skillsexchangenetwork.net>" . "\r\n";
 $SendMail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you put the 's' consequently at the end of $header?

Comment: That's now corrected byt still get mal formed headers and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

[PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) could be a useful solution.

Comment: I've been using that and have even used code from a previous page I wrote that works perfectly but get these errors.