# PHP mail system that sends a HTML email

Tags: php, html, css, email

So, bascially I'm trying to get an email to send from a support form, and when it sends I want it to use a specified CSS file and html. The message sends and all of the PHP sector is complete, but this is how the email appears:

```
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://jake-brunton.com/wtf/corner/contact/mailerCss.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="top">A new query &#92; question!</div>
<br />
<div id="mBody">
    <b> Email </b>: tester@testmail.net<br />
    <b> Subject </b>: Test Subject<br />
    <b> Name </b>: Jake Bdawg<br />
    <b> Message</b>: <br /> Jkat is my other name
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my first time trying something like this aswell. I already use the escape slash in PHP to make sure the quotations do not mess anything up, but I still can't get it to display in HTML. Here's the PHP file:

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subjectName = $_POST['subject'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$messageText = $_POST['message'];

$to = "test@weeshare.ws"; 
$from = " $email ";
$subject = " $subject ";

$message ="<html>
<head>
<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"http://jake-brunton.com/wtf/corner/contact/mailerCss.css\">
</head>
<body>
<div id=\"top\">A new query &#92; question!</div>
<br />
<div id=\"mBody\">
<b> Email </b>: $email<br />
<b> Subject </b>: $subjectName<br />
<b> Name </b>: $name<br />
<b> Message</b>: <br /> $messageText
</div>
</body>
</html>";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0rn"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1rn"; 
$headers  .= "From: $from\r\n"; 
mail($message);

echo "<center>Message Sent Successfully! We\'ll reply within 2 to 4 business days. Please return to the <a href=\"http://jake-brunton.com/wtf/corner\">Home page</a>";
?>
```

Anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: First of all, most email services will tear your stylesheet apart and throw it out, especially Google. Use inline CSS for better results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending HTML email from PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058897/sending-html-email-from-php)

Comment: And your headers are incorrect. Read up => http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 2):

Your headers are incorrect.

Base yourself on the following:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$headers .= "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
            "Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

as per the manual on `mail()` and `headers()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Also, do keep in mind that many email services will ignore your stylesheet, especially Google.

- Use inline CSS for better results.

Answer (score 0):

```
 htmlspecialchars_decode($message);
```

will allow special html characters to be placed in the string

and a content type of :

```
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```