# Email template broken up. Showing HTML tags

Tags: twig, html-email, email-templates

I am trying to send an email on form submit to the client i work for but he is getting is broken up. The email is showing up html tags.

Template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div> 
<h1>New Tour Request</h1>
 <hr>

 <b> Registration For:</b> {{ tour_name|default('N/A')|escape }} <br>  
  <h3> Total Adults:</h3> {{ adult_passengers|default('N/A')|escape }} <br> 

  {% if(adult_passengers > 0) %}

   {% for i in 1 .. adult_passengers %}

         <b>First Name:</b> {{ adult_first_name[i-1]|default('N/A')|escape }}<br>
         <b>Last Name:</b> {{ adult_last_name[i-1]|default('N/A')|escape }}<br>  

    {% endfor %}

  {% endif %}

<h3>Total Children:</h3> {{ child_passengers|default('N/A')|escape }}<br>

  {% if(child_passengers > 0) %}

    {% for i in 1 .. child_passengers %}

          <b>First Name:</b> {{ child_first_name[i-1]|default('N/A')|escape }}<br>
          <b>Last Name:</b> {{ child_last_name[i-1]|default('N/A')|escape }}<br>

    {% endfor %}

  {% endif %}

  <b>Departure Date:</b> {{ departure_date|default('N/A')|escape }}<br>
  <b>Departure City:</b> {{ departure_city|default('N/A')|escape }}<br>
  <b>Flexibility:</b> {{ departure_flexibility|default('N/A')|escape }}<br>
  <b>Earliest date I can leave:</b> {{ depart_day|default('N/A')|escape }}<br>
  <b>Latest date I can be back:</b> {{ back_day|default('N/A')|escape }}<br>
  <b>Email Address:</b> {{ email_address|default('N/A')|escape }}<br>
  <b>Telephone:</b> {{ tel1 ~ tel2 ~ tel3 }}<br>
  <b>Message:</b> {{ special_message|default('N/A')|escape }}<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how the client is receiving the email

```
"\n\n\n \n<\/head>\n\n
\n\n
New Tour Request<\/h1>\n

\n\n
\n
Registration For: Trip Title <\/li> \n
Total Adults: 1 <\/li>\n<\/ul> \n \n
\n
First Name:<\/b> CustomerFN <\/li>\n
Last Name:<\/b> CustomerLN <\/li>

\n <\/ul>\n \n <\/ul>\n
\n
Total Children: 0<\/li>\n <\/ul> \n
\n
Departure Date: 04\/02\/2014<\/li>\n
Flexibility: <\/li>\n
Earliest date I can leave: 04\/03\/2014<\/li>\n
Latest date I can be back: 04\/25\/2014<\/li>\n
Email Address: me@testing.com <\/li>\n
Telephone: 1111111111<\/li>\n
Message: Testing Message <\/li>\n
```

I also tried sending email using this [format](http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/html/) but it was showing only "\n\n\n" and nothing else. I do not know what could be the problem but it is really weird.

Comment: You need to set your [mime version and content type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058897/sending-html-email-from-php)  to render the content as html

Comment: Where to add them @John - I tried adding <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/plain;" charset="us-ascii" /> in the template file but it did not work

Comment: How are you sending it? What code is doing the sending when they submit the form? Here is another good [PHP tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/)

Answer (score 1):

Your mail function should be like this:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

With the `$headers` variable like this:

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
```

(Should be defined before the mail function)

Hope it works.